# Can anyone briefly explain me the following code?

Tags: image-processing, matlab

Here is one of the step of MATLAB code for counting the number of objects in an image.

```
B = bwboundaries(img2);
imshow(img2)
text(10,10,strcat('\color{green}Objects Found:',num2str(length(B))))
hold on
```

Although the explanation given for the code was

```
> This step finds the boundaries of each object that it finds and stores
> it in B. The text function prints the number of objects that are found
> by bwboundaries.
```

But i cannot understand the step 3. Can anyone briefly explain the code for each line.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For help with `bwboundaries` see [the help file for that function](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/images/ref/bwboundaries.html).

`imshow(img2)`

... shows the image `img2` in a figure window.

```
length(B)
```

...gives the scalar length of the vector (or matrix) B, e.g. `8`.

```
num2str(length(B))
```

...converts this number to a string, e.g. `'8'`.

```
strcat('\color{green}Objects Found:',num2str(length(B)))
```

...appends to the start of the string `'8'` the string `\color{green}Objects Found:`. In this case, you would end up with a full string:

```
\color{green}Objects Found:8
```

The `text` function positions this text at the designated position on the current axes, in this case the position (10, 10). The tricky part of this is the `\color{green}` part of the text string, which tells MATLAB to make the text green (and is not shown when the text is plotted).

```
`hold on`
```

... prevents new items plotted to the same axes from erasing the current items.

You can learn about most of these commands from MATLAB by using the `help` command. E.g. typing `help bwboundaries`:

```
>> help bwboundaries
 bwboundaries Trace region boundaries in binary image.
    B = bwboundaries(BW) traces the exterior boundary of objects, as well
    as boundaries of holes inside these objects. It also ... <snip>
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @BillCheatman's answer you probably need to understand what BWBOUNDARIES functioni is doing and what it's returns. Look at the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwboundaries.html) for full explanation and examples.

You will also find that

> bwboundaries returns B, a P-by-1 cell array, where P is the number of
>   objects and holes.

So the statement `length(B)` will give you the largest dimention of cell array `B`, which is `P` in the above citation or number of objects found.

Answer (score 1):

"text(10,10,strcat('\color{green}Objects Found:',num2str(length(B)))) " This line is to write a line of text at the position of (10,10) on the image.

"B = bwboundaries(img2);" this one is to compute the boundary of img2 which should be a binary image.

Let us take this image as an example:
[image]

From this image, we can see that there are four edges. So using "B = bwboundaries(img2);", we will have B which is a 4-cell data. Each cell is a n*2 matrix which stores every edge point coordinates. So each line of the matrix is a edge point. For the example we have, there are four edges and their figures are shown as follows. 
[image]